# How can I run both nginx and Apache together on Ubuntu?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, nginx

I want to configure both Apache and nginx to run together on Ubuntu because I want to develop on both nginx and Apache. I have read that I have to edit the configuration on Apache or nginx to make one of them run on another port rather than 80.

Which files should I edit in Nginx to make it run through another port?

Comment: You've answered your own question and are correct, you need to have different ports for each daemon/server. What have you tried so far? Have you installed both packages and looked at changing the configuration?

Comment: thanks apesa. Can you tell me which files need to be edited for nginx to make it run on another port but not 80? As I would run apache on 80.

Comment: One interesting aspect, though, is that both installers have a `/var/www/index.html` file. So the second server you install is going to show the other server front page by default once it is up and running properly.

Comment: @AlexisWilke: good point. So before installing the second server it's better to copy that file to another name (`index.htm` perhaps?) then change the welcome page setting to point to the renamed file. And only then install the second server.

Comment: Btw, I wonder what `dpkg` thinks of 2 packages "sharing"/overriding the same file... oh, the conflicts on `apt upgrade` might be sweet...

Comment: @MestreLion Yeah, you'd get an error, but you can still force the install. You can save the file if you'd like, it's really not an important file. What I would do anyway is edit the two servers settings and change the default `/var/www` as root to maybe something like `/var/www/<name-of-website>` (or `/var/www/<name-of-server>/<name-of-website>` but then you have an extra sub-directory which may not really help much).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

go to `/etc/nginx/sites-available` then modify the host file which should listen to a different port (if you didn't change anything here you will find a `default` file, enter to change it)

in the file change `listen: 80` to the port you want to listen to

don't forget to reload the service: `service nginx reload`

Comment: Thanks that worked! I tried it earlier as well but I was trying to access the site without port number. So after changing the default file and changing the port to 8080, i was able to access the site at: www.mysite.com:8080 ..

Answer (score 30):

It's better to make `apache` listen on a different port and instruct `nginx` to **reverse-proxy dynamic traffic** to your `apache` while serving **static files** by `nginx`.

For apache in `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` include:

```
Listen 8080
```

For further information refer:
https://serverfault.com/questions/92943/server-has-apache-installed-how-to-install-nginx-alongside-it

Comment: Any justification for why it's better to have Apache to listen on a different port? Easier to do? Better performance?

Comment: I think it's for better performance. `nginx` is built from bottom up as a reverse proxy and static pages web server, and seems it performs the best with static pages (best concurrency management, plus, no interpreter loaded if no need), while `apache` performs better with dynamic pages (interpreters built in). I believe `apache` could do reverse proxy things too, but it is trickier than with `nginx`, and, it seems we loose some interesting `apache` features by doing so.

Comment: Upvoted because I think the logic is correct… But, more detailed answer would be appreciated: why `nginx` upfront, and, more procedural details...

Comment: Easier to do, dear @weezilla

Comment: @hassanketabi: in terms of changing the main listening port, both are equally easy: a single line in a single `/etc/.../conf` file, so that's a proper explanation. I believe @cedbeu's rationale is much more sensible and a proper justification

Answer (score 19):

### Here is the answer how to have both Apache and NGINX installed on the same 80 port (on localhost).

Assuming that you have both NGINX and Apache installed...

**1. Select different IP addresses for each one.**

Let's setup the `hosts` file for quick access to start pages.

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

append lines (use any local IP you like)

```
127.0.0.1   nginx
127.0.0.2   apache
```

**2. Setup listen IP and port for NGINX**

NGINX must listen on one IP address only.

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

And replace the lines

*--- (remove lines)*
*+++ (add lines)*

```
--- listen 80 default_server;
--- listen [::]:80 default_server;
+++ listen nginx:80;
```

If you want to use SSL, make the same things for 443 port.

> **IMPORTANT!**
>
> **Make sure all enabled NGINX websites listen on nginx:80**

Restart NGINX

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

Make a check using command `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :80`

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      26540/nginx: master
```

Done! Now you can access default NGINX host by url http://nginx

**3. Setup listen IP and port for Apache**

Apache must listen on one IP address only as well.

Ports:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/ports.conf
```

And replace the lines

*--- (remove lines)*
*+++ (add lines)*

```
--- Listen 80
--- Listen 443
+++ Listen apache:80
+++ Listen apache:443
```

Default virtual host:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache/sites-enabled/000-default
```

And replace the lines

*--- (remove lines)*
*+++ (add lines)*

```
--- <VirtualHost *:80>
+++ <VirtualHost apache:80>
```

If you want to use SSL, make the same things for 443 port.

> **IMPORTANT!**
>
> **Make sure all enabled Apache websites listen on apache:80**

Restart Apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Make a check using command `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :80`

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.2:80            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      26829/apache2
```

Done! Now you can access default Apache host by url http://apache

Comment: That's a very clever trick to enable both on the same 80/443 ports, but... be aware that this way your server will only listen to requests _from your own machine_. They won't respond to neither LAN nor internet requests

Comment: Still, +1 for a very detailed guide on _where_ to change ports for _both_ servers. And, if anyone simply wants to change the port _number_ (from, say, 80 to 8080), just ignore the first part about editing `/etc/hosts`

Comment: is there any way to make this solution working not only on my own machine?
anyway thank you, this is the most complete guide step by step, the most useful.. thank you thank you

Answer (score 8):

so i had a similar problem i had Apache running on Ubuntu 14.04 and i had to install nginx alongside the Apache so after installing nginx i changed the listening port of the ngnix server from default 80 to 81 and it did the magic follow the below instruction to achieve it

```
cd /etc/nginx/sites-available
sudo cp default default.bak
sudo nano default
```

change port here .

```
server {
listen 81 default_server;
listen [::]:81 default_server ipv6only=on;
```

save it and get out of nano 
then restart the ngnix with

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

and in browser `http://localhost:81` your server is up

`

Answer (score 3):

if apache is running on `port 80` then either you have to change apache listening port or nginx listening port.

> to change nginx listening port:

open `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file with nano or any file editor of your choice and then change these 2 lines

```
 listen 80 default_server;
 listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
```

to

```
 listen 8000 default_server;
 listen [::]:8000 default_server ipv6only=on;
```

if `port 8000` is not bound to any other service.

and then reload nginx using `service nginx reload`

Answer (score 1):

I got it resolved by changing the ports in apache ports.conf file

you can edit it by:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/ports.conf
```

and if you want to change the port for nginx one then just change it in the file in site-available